# dw_1.print(false) PDF generated is always blank

Tags: ghostscript, powerbuilder, postscript, datawindow, powerbuilder-pfc

```
ll_printed = dw_1.print(FALSE)

IF ll_printed = 1 AND FileLength64(gs_TmpFile) > 100000 THEN

ls_run =gs_GhostScript_Path + "gswin32c -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-sOutputFile=" + gs_TmpFile + ".pdf " + " -dBATCH -dNOPAGEPROMPT -dNOPROMPT-dQUIET -dNOPAUSE" +' ' + gs_TmpFile

END IF
```

I got this script where I check the file length, I always generate a PS with 11kb. If i continue to create a pdf. it will create a blank PDF. Sometimes It actually print the correct information sometimes its blank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you appear to be testing the size of gs_TmpFile to see if its more than 100,000 bytes, and yet you say you always generate an 11Kb (11264 bytes) PostScript program, so I can't see how you ever manage to invoke Ghostscript in that case.

I'd guess that your temporary file is still not complete, or does not contain what you think it does.

Of course, you have set -dQUIET, suppressing messages, and not bothered to provide (or even capture) the Ghostscript transcript. Most likely there's something in there that would give you a clue, but since you haven't presented it, nobody can tell.

You need to do considerably more debugging of this yourself. You should  capture the PostScript program at the time you invoke Ghostscript (copy it to a new file), and also capture the Ghostscript output. Then examine the PDF file that is created, until you hit your error condition.

When you hit the error condition you will be in a position to compare the PostScript program that was sent to Ghostscript with a working version, and you will have any information Ghostscript wanted you to be aware of, which may help you debug the problem.

There's really not sufficient information here to offer any more help.

Comment: Actually from here `dw_1.print(FALSE)` the file generated is already 11kb, so I will not continue to convert when its blank. Now im wondering how come this `dw_1.print(FALSE)` will result to a 11kb file even though is has value.

Comment: PostScript is a programming language. Many PostScript print systems start by defining all the procedures they intend to sue, which can be extensive. In addition, many printing systems create DSC (Document Structure Convention) compliant files, which contain a number of comments with metadata, and are structured in a particular fashion. 11Kb is not that much for a computer generated PostScript program. From your question I understtod you to be saying the file was always 11Kb in size. If that's not the case then I suspect you are starting to process it before its complete, and GS throws an error

Comment: I allotted 120 seconds wait time before it process the next step. What this datawindow have is an ole object microsoft web browser control where I go to specific url wait 120 second before I print the datawindow.

Comment: Well, I've given you suggestions for debugging the problem. Right at the moment there's nothing more I can say without more information.

Comment: Printing is an asynchronous activity. I propose that you monitor gs_TmpFile. I haven't tried, but, I suspect that if gs_TmpFile exists and you tried to open gs_TmpFile read/lock it would fail until windows completed writing the file. Make sure that you give windows plenty of time to start printing before you lock gs_TmpFile. Let me know if you'd like some example code.